# Alternative to multi-node and fugue on Windows?

Tags: node.js

Is there an alternative to multi-node and fugue for Windows? I am able to install multi-node, but it doesn't run on Windows because of its dependency on process.bind("net") and I can't get fugue to install.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out [Cluster](http://learnboost.github.com/cluster/)? It seems to be the recommended way of running multiple node instances these days.